# In Angular2 how can I get the object I did return in a custom validator when it failed?

Tags: angular, custom-validators

Let's say I've got this custom validator, I was wondering whether there is a way to use the object we return when the validation fails.

```
export class PasswordValidator{

    private static min:number = 3;
    private static max:number = 32;

    static setMin(n:number){ PasswordValidator.min = n; }
    static setMax(n:number){ PasswordValidator.max = n; }

    static validatePw(ctrl:FormControl){
        let err:number = 0;
        let pw = ctrl.value;

        err += pw.length < PasswordValidator.min ? 1 : 0;
        err += pw.length > PasswordValidator.max ? 1 : 0;
        err += (/([a-z\-]*[A-Z].*[\d][a-z\-]*)|([a-z\-]*[\d].*[A-Z][a-z\-]*)/).test(pw) ? 0 : 1;

        return err > 0 ? {validatePw:"it is a valid goHenry password"} : null;

    }

}
```

For example doing (in the main component):

```
errortMsg = this.myform.controls['password'].validatePw
```

because I don't see the point to return an object if we I can't use it.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the `errors` property of the control:

```
errortMsg = this.myform.controls['password'].errors.validatePw
```